# How to interpret Plotting results Ordinary Ridge regression (check EDIT)

Tags: python, plot, regression

I am trying to visualize the results of my regression (First time I do a regression be merciful). [This](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html) is the example I am following but it creates a mess of a plot (tbh I took this example at face value). I have two issues. One is the visualization. The other, is an error I get when plotting trying to plot `x_validate` Vs. `y_validate`. I get `ValueError: x and y must be the same size` but they both have `56 rows`. This is the code:

```
# This is where I create the three parts
bow.fillna(0, inplace=True)
x_train, x_validate, x_test = np.split(bow.sample(frac=1), [int(.6*len(bow)), int(.8*len(bow))])
y_train = x_train['Rating']
y_validate = x_validate['Rating']
y_test = x_test['Rating']
x_train.drop('Rating', 1, inplace=True)
x_validate.drop('Rating', 1, inplace=True)
x_test.drop('Rating', 1, inplace=True) 

# This is the regression part
regr = m.OrdinalRidge()
regr.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = regr.predict(x_validate)

# This is the plotting
plt.scatter(x_validate, y_validate,  color='black')  # <-- Here is where I get the error
plt.plot(x_validate, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=1)
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())
plt.show()
```

This is what `x_validate` looks like:

[image]

This is what `y_validate` looks like:

[image]

This is what `y_pred` looks like:

[image]

The `.size` of the above are:

`x_validate` -> 3976 (but it has `56 rows` and `71 columns`)

`y_validate` -> `56`

`y_pred` -> `56`

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

This is the code as suggested by `Ach113` :

```
pca = PCA(n_components = 1) # the n will be 2 here since y in your case has 2 columns
pca.fit(x_validate)
x_validate = pca.transform(x_validate)

plt.scatter(x_validate, y_validate,  color='black')
plt.plot(x_validate, y_pred, color='blue', linewidth=1)

plt.show()
```

And this is what the resulting plot looks like:

[image]

How can I interpret if the regression is performing well? I'm a bit lost...

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of features have to match with dimension of output in order for the plotting to work. The dimensions of X and Y have to match exactly, for that you will have to reduce the dimension of X by using PCA:

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA

pca = PCA(n_components = n) # the n will be 2 here since y in your case has 2 columns
pca.fit(x_train)
x_train = pca.transform(x_train)
```

Comment: Thx, but if i do this won't I be losing data?

Comment: @Stefano, you could use it for only visualization and make regression on your normal data

Comment: ty for the help. Could I ask you to look at the edit if it's not too much to ask?

Comment: @Stefano, I am not entirely sure but I think the problem is the fact that (1.0, 2.0 ... 5.0) values in your y column are discrete values instead of being continuous, and regression needs to take continuous values as its Y for it to work.

Comment: Indeed they are discrete, but that's why I use ordinal regression (I thought that was the purpose of it, I might be wrong though)